# Angular: How to get an input value using $this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, keyup

I am hoping to get an input value inside a keyup function that can runs from multiple inputs. Every time there is a keyup the function will trigger according to the specific input. So, I am trying to use $this inside the function. No succes so far..
HTML code:

```
<input ng-keyup="getRxcui()" placeholder="Type med a" id="medicineA" />
<input ng-keyup="getRxcui()" placeholder="Type med b" id="medicineB" />
```

Angular code:

```
var rxConflicts = angular.module('rxConflicts', []);

rxConflicts.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.getRxcui = function(event){

        // getting the value for each medicine input
        var medValue = $(this).value;
        console.log(medValue);

    }
});
```

I am pretty sure $(this) is the right way to do this so that I don't need to duplicate that function for each input and use ng-model... You can take my word that the angular works fine.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that $(this) is jquery?

Comment: yes, how can i achieve it in angular?

Comment: Looks like somebody already answered that for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use ng-model and pass it in function:

```
<input ng-keyup="getRxcui(medicineA)" ng-model="medicineA" placeholder="Type med a" id="medicineA" />
<input ng-keyup="getRxcui(medicineB)" ng-model="medicineB" placeholder="Type med b" id="medicineB" />
```

Angular code:

```
var rxConflicts = angular.module('rxConflicts', []);

rxConflicts.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.getRxcui = function(value){

        // getting the value for each medicine input
        var medValue = value;
        console.log(medValue);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Angular 2 and superior:

You could pass the $event on the keyUp and use it to get the target (the input) and it's value. In case you're using formControls and not binding directly through ngModel

Template HTML:

```
<input (keyup)="getRxcui($event)">
```

Component.ts

```
getRxcui(event){

   var inputValue = event.target.value;
   console.log(inputValue);

}
```